# Manipulate the output of if any for loop

Tags: python, match, any

I need to compare the following `sequences` list items:

`sequences = ['sphere_v002_', 'sphere_v002_0240_', 'test_single_abc_f401']`

to:

`folder = 'sphere_v002'`

and then work on the list items containing `folder`.

I have a working function for this but I want to improve it.

Current code is:

```
foundSeq = False

for seq in sequences:
    headName = os.path.splitext(seq.head())[0]

    #Check name added exception for when name has a last underscore                 
    if headName == folder or headName[:-1] == folder:
        foundSeq = True
        sequence = seq

if not foundSeq:
    ...
```

My improvement looks like this:

```
if any(folder in os.path.splitext(seq.head())[0] for seq in sequences):
    print seq
```

But then I get the following error:

`local variable seq referenced before the assignment`

How can I get the correct output working with the improved solution?

Comment: Perhaps use the `filter` function..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by jpp, `any` just return a boolean. So the if any is not the good solution in this particular case.

Like suggested by thebjorn, the most efficient code for us so far consists in the use of `filter` function.

```
sequences = ['sphere_v002_', 'sphere_v002_0240_', 'test_single_abc_f401']
match = filter(lambda x: 'sphere_v002' == x[:-1] or 'sphere_v002' == x, sequences)
print match
['sphere_v002_']
```

Answer (score 1):

`any` returns a Boolean value only, it won't store in a variable `seq` the element within `sequences` when your condition is satisfied.

What you can do is use a generator and utilize the fact `None` is "Falsy":

```
def get_seq(sequences, folder):
    for seq in sequences:
        if folder in os.path.splitext(seq.head())[0]:
            yield seq

for seq in get_seq(sequences, folder):
    print seq
```

You can rewrite this, if you wish, as a generator expression:

```
for seq in (i for i in sequences if folder in os.path.splitext(i.head())[0]):
    print seq
```

If the condition is never specified, the generator or generator expression will not yield any values and the logic within your loop will not be processed.